# DAZ Dragon Slayer Sword not attached to character In Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

After Following many tutorials how to create animations in DAZ to attaching the clothes while exporting to FBX. I am successful to an extent. (If any one is new, this video tutorials helps a lot) Visit http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKC-gFtM5pE

But, the problem is, the sword is showing at a distance in the Unity. I mean the sword is not in the hands of the Dragon Slayer but, in the air.

In Daz, this animation has no problem, problem is only in Unity. Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and just unchecked "Apply root motion" of animation and it worked. Try...

Comment: Thank you for the response. After your suggestion i tried to look in unity docs [http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/RootMotion.html] and apply it to the character. it did not worked. Thier are Root Transform Rotation, Position Y and XZ. You are talking about this only right

Comment: Jan, "Apply root motion" i unchecked it. Also, i tried to chnage the rig to Humanoid, generic etc.  Still, the same problem. I am trying, but, if you have any thing in mind please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try to parent the sword to the character's hand.  In other words, put the sword into the character's object tree, so that it's a child of the character's hand that's holding it.  This way, it will move relative to the hand's position.